# Removing </b> for Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, sql-server-2012

I have a php like bellow. I need a true/false response from php. When I testing on web browser it is ok like '{"success":false}' but when I test in android it is giving error like 'java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject' I found that in android the response from php also include this `.</b> on line <b>8</b><br />.` So i cannot check the response whether it is true or false how to remove this from php I need only the repose like {"success":false}.
The bellow php

```
<?php
include 'test.php';
$response = array();
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM material WHERE matid='".$username."' and itname='".$password."' ";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if ($row_count>0) {
$response["success"] = true;
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
$response["success"] = true;
$response["name"] =$row['matid'];
$response["age"] = $row['color'];
$response["username"] = $row['color'];
$response["password"] = $row['itname'];
    }
 }
else {
$response["success"] = false;  
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand how your response looks like but you can use String.replace  to remove those annoying characters.

Comment: You can reply with an answer only that shows where the problem is, otherwise, you should use the comment feature and it seems you are new and you don't have that privilege so you need to earn it first with replying with correct and accurate answers